# Import data into Matlab from Columnstore table in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, matlab, import, export

I wanted to import data into MATLAB from a columnstore table in sql server 2016. I have code working for rowstore tables, but now the code returns error like:

> ODBC Driver Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cursors are not supported on a table which has a clustered columnstore index.

The code is as following:

```
clear
conn=database.ODBCConnection('sql_server','','');
setdbprefs( 'DataReturnFormat' ,'table');
sql1 = 'select top 100 * from tab1';
curs=exec(conn, sql1);
curs.Message
```

How should I fixed such error? Should I switch to SQL server native client?

I'm using Matlab 2016a with SQL server 2016 developer edition on Win10 64bit

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35411122/4221706) is the exact same question, just for java instead of MATLAB. Can you check, if you have the option `selectmethod` somewhere? Maybe in the database object, or using `setdbprefs`?

Comment: @hbaderts, thanks for your comment! I read that questions before I posted this one. I looked over the help pages for commands "exec", "setdbprefs", and didn't find options corresponding to "direct" cursor.