# Matlab database error: Cursors are not supported on a table which has a clustered columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, matlab, odbc

I am trying to connect SQL with Matlab in order to have data directly in Matlab. I am using the database explorer in matlab and on the left panel I can see the table included in the server, so I was able to connect successfully Matlab with the ODBC datasource.

When I try to run a query in the database explorer I receive the following error message: "Cursors are not supported on a table which has a clustered columnstore index".

I also tried to create the following code:

```
%% Settings
clc
close all
clear all

%% Set preferences
prefs = setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat');
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','table')

%% Make connection to database
conn = database('database','userID','PassWD');
conn.Message %check connection, if [] the connection is successful
%% Execute query and fetch results
curs = exec(conn,['SELECT top (20)* FROM db_database']);
curs = fetch(curs)
data = curs.Data
close(curs)
```

Still not working. Do you have any suggestion to deal with this?

Comment: Looks like you need to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411122/sqlexceptionhelper-cursors-are-not-supported-on-a-table-which-has-a-clustered-c) to happen in your Matlab database connection. Try doing `conn = database('database','userID','PassWD', 'selectmethod', 'direct');`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, selectmethod is not supported in the `database` object

Comment: Well, crap. Maybe you could extract the ODBC `Connection` object from inside the Matlab `database` object and fiddle with its properties directly?